# How to make an image smaller while leaving the it in it's original proportions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to add a list of images from my Google drive to a Google doc using Google apps script.
I made a list named **images_list** of links to the images that are in my Drive.
I was able to add all the content I need to the doc and the images at the end of it.

Currently the images are huge in their size, and I turned it into 400X400.
The problem is that not all them are square.

How can I make the image smaller while leaving the image in it's original proportions?

This is the code I'm using:

```
  if(images_list[0]){
    for(var i=0; i<images_list.length; i++){
      try{
        var imageID = images_list[i].slice(32,65);
        var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(imageID).getBlob();
        var imgDoc = body.appendImage(blob);
        imgDoc.setWidth(400).setHeight(400)
        bullet_index = bullet_index+1
      }catch(e){}
    }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you can get its original height and width with `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` calculate the proportions and calculate destination size based on the proportions. But you need decide first what exactly you want to do with vertical and horizontal images. Should they have 400 pix by bigger or smaller side?

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

For example it could be something like this:

```
if (images_list[0]) {
  for (var i = 0; i < images_list.length; i++) {
    try {
      var imageID = images_list[i].slice(32, 65);
      var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(imageID).getBlob();

      var max = 400;
      var w = imgDoc.getWidth();
      var h = imgDoc.getHeight();
      if (w > h) { h = h * (max / w); w = max }
      else { w = w * (max / h); h = max }

      imgDoc.setWidth(w).setHeight(h);

      bullet_index = bullet_index + 1
    } catch (e) { }
  }
}
```

It will fit any image into a square 400x400 px while keeping the aspect ratio.